# Set the value in a column within a SELECT query

Tags: sql, sql-server, ms-access, sql-update

I have two (simplified) tables as follows:

Table AAPT

| Well | Type | Comment |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | PT | Good |
| B | PT-S | Average |

Table AASPIN

| Well | Type | Remark |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | PT | Bad |
| B | PT-S | Fair |

I want to run a SELECT query that results in the following:

| Well | Type | Comment | Remark | PTType | SpinType |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | SPINPT | Good | Bad | PT | SPIN |
| B | SPINPT | Average | Fair | PT-S | SPIN-PT |

I use both MS Access and SQL-Server.

In Access, I use the following query:

```
SELECT A.Well, A.Type, A.Comment, B.Remark, A.Type AS PTType, B.Type AS SpinType
FROM AAPT A, AASPIN B
WHERE A.Well = B.Well
```

However, I do not know how to set the value of the Type column to "SPINPT"

Any suggestions?

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I am more comfortable with old-style joins, having started using SQL over 30 years ago (Paradox for DOS).  Can you show me how to set the constant string aliased as the column name.  Everything I try doesn't give the results I want.

Comment: Sorry nothing I try works.  Could you edit my query to the precise format that is required.  Thanks.

Comment: No you didn't.  You did not specify where I put the phrase in the query.  Just rewrite my query with the addition you suggest.

Comment: The alias names (PTType and SpinPTType) are not the same as any existing field name.  I need to retain the Type field in the query, but with the value "SPINPT" , and need to retain the information of the Type field so it is put in an Aliased field.  Replacing `A.Type` with `"SPINPT" AS A.Type'` fails in MS Access. And I wish to solve this problem with a single query.  I realise I can select into a temporary table and then do an UPDATE query, but I would prefer to use a single query if possible..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a modern explicit join and a static value for `Type`:

```
SELECT
    A.Well
    , 'SPINPT' AS [Type]
    , A.Comment
    , B.Remark
    , A.[Type] AS PTType
    , B.[Type] AS SpinType
FROM AAPT A
INNER JOIN AASPIN B ON A.Well = B.Well;
```